# Redirect to default node url

Tags: 7, nodes, routes, redirection

I have an question about drupal's redirect.

Well I implemented hook_menu for the path: "node/%node/boost".

And I set all callbacks from default node path: "node/%node".

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['node/%node/boost'] = array(
    'title callback' => 'node_page_title',
    'title arguments' => array(1),
    'page callback' => 'node_page_view',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
    'access arguments' => array('view', 1),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

So I would get the node from my custom URL

but I got the redirect to default node URL like "node/123".

Any idea how can I load nodes from the my custom URL?

Thanks

**UPD**

If I change "page callback" function to the my custom function "my_module_page_view", for example:

```
/**
 * Callback.
 */
function my_module_page_view($node) {
  return 'Hello Drupal!';
}
```

I will see the text "Hello Drupal!" on the page with URL "/node/1/boost".

But if I use the next code:

```
/**
 * Callback.
 */
function my_module_page_view($node) {
  return node_view($node);
}
```

I will get redirect from "/node/1/boost" to "/node/1"

Comment: Are you saying that you visit node/123/boost, and you are redirected to node/123, or are you saying you want the user redirected from node/123/boost to node/123?

Comment: It happens. But I don't need it.

Comment: It seems the menu item didn't registered. Did you clear cache after adding this?

Comment: I would agree with @JimmyKo, but redirecting from node/1/boost to node/1 when node/1/boost didn't get registered is not the default behavior a plain installation of Drupal 7 has. If I create a node (whose ID is 1) and I visit node/1/random-long-string-no-module-uses, I am not redirected in any way. It could be you installed a module that redirects you when you try to access a non registered route like node/1/boost. That, added to the fact Drupal doesn't recognize node/%node/boost as route could explain the behavior you are noticing.

Comment: @kiamlaluno According to my memory, I remember that it would redirect **node/1/boost** to **node/1** if there is no node/1/boost router in the database. **boost** should become the second parameter of the page callback of **node/1** automatically.

Comment: @JimmyKo It doesn't redirect you: It shows the content of the page with the closer path. Redirecting would meant that the URL in the browser address bar would change from http://example.com/node/1/boost to http://example.com/node/1, but that doesn't happen, in Drupal 7 or earlier version.

Comment: Oh yes... `redirect` means the change on URL. Does @silvorezka misunderstand the meaning of `redirect` as I did?

Answer (score 0):

Well It was a monkey's code in the one custom module: It implements `hook_node_view()` and, if the path  was similar to node/1/bla-bla, it redirected users to node/1.